# CLone github into netbeans project and problem: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null

Tags: java, github, netbeans, clone

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException:
> Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is
> null

I need help please! When I clone code from GitHub into NetBeans, I cannot run the project code that I cloned because of this issue: "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null"".

I searched and I think it may be because the images in project, but I don't know how to fix it.

[image]